# Algorithm to make a route from Source Node to End Node using every node exactly once

Tags: graph, routes, traveling-salesman, floyd-warshall

I'm trying to create a route, given a start node and end node, that will travel to every single node in the graph, and minimize the cost of doing so.

The graph is undirected, and every node is connected to each other directly. The weight of every edge is positive. I think because every node connects to eachother, that there are many "loops" in my graph, but I don't want to generate a route with a loop in it.

So, for a graph with N nodes, I have (N*N-1) directed edges. A graph with nodes A,B,C,D would have edges:

- A to B / B to A
- A to C / C to A
- A to D / D to A
- B to C / C to B
- C to D / D to C
- B to D / D to B

When I implement the Floyd Warshall algorithm from Wikipedia, I only ever get an array of 2 nodes. There's a function in the article that gives you the shortest path from node U to node V, and that's the function that only returns [U,V] (array containing U and V)

I MUST be misunderstanding what it is exactly that Floyd Warshall is meant to solve. I'll attach my code to show how I've implemented it in javascript.

```
    function colorsToEdgeMatrix(colors){
        var dist = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < colors.length;i++){
        dist[i] = [];
        var c1 = colors[i];
        for(var j = 0; j < colors.length;j++){
           if(i == j){continue;}
        var c2 = colors[j];
        dist[i][j] = colorDistance(c1,c2);
        }
    }
    return dist;
}
    function colorsToNextMatrix(colors){
        var next = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < colors.length;i++){
            next[i] = [];
            for(var j = 0; j < colors.length;j++){
                if(i == j){continue;}
                next[i][j] = j;
            }
        }
        return next;
    }
    //lab colors
    function FloydWarshallWithPathReconstruction (colors){
       var next = [];
       var dist = colorsToEdgeMatrix(colors);
       var next = colorsToNextMatrix(colors);
       var N = colors.length;
        for(var k = 0; k < N; k++){ // standard Floyd-Warshall implementation
            for(var i = 0; i < N; i++){
                for(var j = 0; j < N; j++){
                    if(dist[i][k] + dist[k][j] < dist[i][j]){
                       dist[i][j] = dist[i][k] + dist[k][j]
                       next[i][j] = next[i][k]
                    }
                }
            }
       }
       return next;
    }

    function Path(next,u, v) {
       var path = [];
       if(next[u][v] == null){
           return []
       }
       path = [u]
       while(u != v){
           u = next[u][v]
           path.push(u)
       }
       return path;
    }


    var lab = randomLABArray(100); //make an array of LAB color space colors. a LAB element has an array structure [L,a,b]
    lab = sortLuminosityLAB(lab); //sorts the LAB colors from light to dark
    var next = FloydWarshallWithPathReconstruction(lab); //gets all paths using floyd warshall
    var path = Path(next, 0, lab.length-1); //gets the path calculated from lightest to darkest
    console.log( path );
```

Does this algorithm not necessarily return a path that goes through every node? I guess what it does is just spits out the best path for every start and end node, and doesn't guarantee any path goes through every node...

I used the Nearest Neighbor algorithm with decent result, and Brute Force is impossible after 10 elements. I was hoping the Floyd Warshall would give even better results

Huh...so this might actually be a Hamiltonian Path problem and isn't as simple as I thought...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be reduced to the Traveling Salesman problem as follows. Pick a large number `M` which is greater than the sum of all weights in the graph. Add this number to the weights on all edges in the graph *except* the edge connecting the start node and the end node. That edge should have its cost set to zero. Solve the resulting Traveling Salesman Problem. It is easy to see that the optimal solution of the TSP will include the edge connecting the start and end node. Throw that edge away from the optimal solution and adjust the weights back to their original value -- and you have found the optimal solution to your problem.

Conversely, the regular TSP can be reduced to your problem in an even easier way. Pick a node at random and duplicate it. Let one of these newly duplicated nodes be the start node and the other be the end node. Solve your optimal path problem for this instance. Then -- remerge these two nodes into the original node, which will splice the ends together to form a circuit, which is easily seen to be optimal. This confirms your intuition that the problem is at least as hard as the Hamiltonian circuit problem.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, and thanks for confirming this is the infamous TSP! I'm going to look at some algorithms to solve it. I just thought of an interesting idea...combine nearest neighbor and randomness...

Basically, choose a start node A..sort all other nodes by weight to A, then choose the first K of these neighbors. Pick one random node from that set. Rinse and repeat until you have the full path

Then, repeat that for N trials, and choose the minimum.

It's really just *luck* because of the randomness, but I'm going to try it too

Comment: Just wanted to give a quick update..I did the "nearest neighbor + randomness" idea. I used a graph with 30 nodes. I found K = 2 to be ideal, and for 10,000 iterations actually consistently found a better path than the nearest neighbors algorithm alone!

Perhaps 10,000 iterations isn't necessary...it took a couple seconds to run the set of 30 elements..

Comment: @applejacks01 There are open source implementations of both exact and heuristic approaches to TSP which are really quite good. It is fun to play around with this, but if you really want good results for larger problems it is hard to beat the fruit of decades of work. The big-M approach could be used with such software (with a certain amount of trial and error to find the lowest M that will cause the software to still pick the end to start node since I suspect that smaller M will result in better numerical stability).

Comment: Definitely fun! I'm messing around with a genetic programming algorithm and its having really good results. I'm going to look into the big-M approach too, thanks for that

Comment: I can't conceive a way to use the big-M method on this problem. I understand big-M method is for solving linear systems, I just can't think of how to implement it with a collection of nodes and edges. I implemented the 2opt algorithm and its producing decent results, but the nearest neighbor algorithm is faster and produces a shorter path

Comment: What I called the big-M method isn't the same thing as what it means in linear programming. The point was simply to modify your problem so that it became an instance of the TSP in which the optimal solution can be interpreted as being an optimal path from start node to end node. Having said that, it certainly makes sense to modify the TSP algorithms to work directly in your situation. 2-opt is a method for *refining* solutions and is typically begun after something like nearest-neighbor leaves off, in which case it will be no worse and almost certainly better than nearest neighbor alone.

Comment: Ahh yeah! I used the 2-opt after the nearest neighbor and its making even better results now. Thanks again for everything